# Where to find raw images of Ultima Thule?

Tags: new-horizons, raw-data, 2014-mu69

I've found the [raw LORRI images](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/soc/UltimaThule-Encounter/) taken by New Horizons at Ultima Thule but haven't been able to find raw MVIC images (or data from the other instruments).  Does anyone know if these are currently publicly available in unprocessed form (or where they will be in future)?

Comment: It will take 20 months for all of the data from the encounter to reach earth. We might need to relax and wait for everything to trickle in. Nobody at the Johns Hopkins University Applied Physics Laboratory wants to hold back information. - https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-46731831

Comment: @gwally I totally grok that.  What I'm trying to find out is whether there are any places where raw(ish) data is being posted that I'm not aware of.  For example, I'm interested in seeing the source image for the IR/R/B MVIC image that was posted (in smoothed form, I think) on [this page](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/Galleries/Featured-Images/image.php?page=1&gallery_id=2&image_id=578).

Answer (score 4):

All the New Horizons data is archived and available at the Small Bodies Node (SBN) of NASA's Planetary Data System (PDS) at [this landing page](https://pds-smallbodies.astro.umd.edu/data_sb/missions/newhorizons/index.shtml). PDS is the main official repository for all NASA planetary data from either space-based or ground-based missions. Since PDS is used as the final archive, there tends to be a small number of data deliveries of large chunks of data. Looking at Table 3 of the [New Horizons Data Management Plan](https://pds-smallbodies.astro.umd.edu/data_sb/missions/newhorizons/05310-DMAP-01_R0_C0.pdf) (which covers the Pluto encounter and not the Extended Mission to Ultima Thule), data were typically delivered to PDS about 9 months after receipt on the ground. The [pluto.jhuapl.edu](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu) site will likely be the best outlet for more immediate data releases if they are made available.